# Automatically Change Date Weekly (php)

Tags: php

Is it possible to update a date every week automatically with php?

For instance, I have a weekly forecast that is updated every Monday. The title would read something like "Forecast for Friday June 28th."

```
<h1>- Forecast for Friday June 28th -</h1>
```

Then on the following monday, I would like to automatically update the date in the title to the next occurring Friday.

is this possible with php?

Comment: it's easy to get the date with the date("Y-m-d") function , however for the days you might look into php libs or native extensions

Comment: So on Satuday 29th it'll show the forecast for the previous day?

Comment: yes, Saturday the 29th it will still show the forecast for Friday. It's a forecast for the whole weekend.

Answer (score 1):

This is what you're looking for:

```
switch (date('N'))
{

  case 5:
    $time = time();
    break;

  case 6:
  case 7:
    $time = strtotime('last Friday');
    break;

  default:
    $time = strtotime('next Friday');

}

echo date('l F jS', $time);
```

Check the [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function for different formatting options.

Although are you sure you want to wait until Monday until showing the forecast for the next Friday? Surely it should update to the following week on the *Saturday* (otherwise you'll be forecasting a past date)? If so, just remove the `case 6`/`case 7` section.

Comment: think of the forecast as a forecast for Friday, Saturday, and Sunday, not just Friday. It's a weekend forecast.
using the string to time function and putting it in a switch lets me control what to display quite nicely. thanks @MichaelRushton

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Take a look at [`date()`](http://php.net/date) for formatting and [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/strtotime) to quickly create relative timestamps:

The following should get you started:

```
echo date('l F jS', strtotime('monday'));
```

**Note:** If you're using PHP > 5.3 you should look at the [DateTime class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php).

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple coded to explain as much simple as possible. The script calculates how many days left until next Friday, if $today is not Friday.

Hope that helps you!

```
<?php
$now    = time(); // current timestamp
$today  = date("w", $now); // "w" returns the weekday (number)
$friday = 5; // 5th day of the week (sunday = 0)

if ($today == $friday) {
    $ts       = $now; // today is friday, don't change the timestamp
    $daysLeft = 0; // no days left!
} else {
    if ($today == 6) {
        $daysLeft = 6; // saturday is bigger then friday
    } else {
        $daysLeft = $friday-$today; // get the left days
    }

    $ts = $now + 84600 * $daysLeft; // now + seconds of one day * days left
}
?>

<h1>
    - Forecast for <?php echo date("D M d", $ts) ?>-
</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$currDay = date('w');
$delta = $currDay==6 ? 6 : 5-$currDay;

$date = new DateTime();
$date->add(new DateInterval('P'.$delta.'D'));
echo $date->format('D M jS');
```